# Как получить объект DataTable из BindingSource?

Tags: c#

Как получить ссылку на `DataTable` из объекта `BindingSource`, если структура построена так:

```
BindingSource bsEmpl = new BindingSource();
bsEmpl.DataSource = ds;
bsEmpl.DataMember = "table_empl";
dgvEml.DataSource = bsEmpl;

BindingSource bsContr = new BindingSource();
bsContr.DataSource = bsEmpl;
bsContr.DataMember = "rel_empl_contract";
dgvContr.DataSource = bsContr;
```

где `ds` это объект класса `DataSet`.
`rel_empl_contract` - имя `DataRelation`, созданное следующим образом:

```
DataRelation rel;
rel = new DataRelation("rel_empl_contract", t_empl.Columns["id"], t_contr.Columns["empl_id"]);
ds.Relations.Add(rel);
```

Суть задачи:

> читая поле `dataGridView.DataSource` получить таблицу `DataTable`, чтобы
> через `foreach` проименовать названия столбцов сетки из свойства `Caption`
> таблицы

Comment: `DataTable dt = (bsEmpl.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[bsEmpl.DataMember];` ? если конечно у вас там DataSet

Answer (score 0):

```
BindingSource bs = dgv.DataSource as BindingSource;
DataTable dt = (bs.DataSource as Dataset).Tables[bs.DataMember];
```

Вероятнее всего это вам подойдёт если у вас DGV привязан к BindingSource (Ну и пусть спустя 2 года , но ответ :) )